# jQuery: How can I put two of these elements on the same page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the following script, but if I put more than 1 occurrence on the same page, it breaks. I am trying to get it to where I can put multiple carousels on the same page.

HTML:

```
<div class="carousel_outer">
    <div class="portfolio-carousel horizontal">
        <div class="carousel" id="carousel1">
            <div class="carousel_container carousel1">
                <ul class="portfolio-wrap carousel1">
                    <li><a class="gall_thumb" href="#" title="First Pic"><img src="#" alt="First Pic" /></a></li>
                    <li><a class="gall_thumb" href="#" title="Second Pic"><img src="#" alt="Second Pic" /></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div> 
            <a class="carousel_prev" href="#">Previous</a>
            <a class="carousel_next" href="#">Next</a>
        </div> 
    </div> 
</div>
```

Javascript on the page:

```
$('.carousel').mycarousel({
    delay: 150,
    fade:300,
    slide: 700,
    effect:'slide',                   
    orientation:'horizontal',
    loop: false,
    autoplay: false
});
```

And the actual carousel javascript:

```
(function ($) {
$.fn.extend({
    mycarousel: function (options) {
        var defaults = {
            delay: 150,
            fade: 300,
            slide: 500,
            effect: "fade",
            orientation: "horizontal",
            captionFade: 150,
            loop: false,
            autoplay: true,
            time: 3000
        };
        var options = $.extend(defaults, options);
        return this.each(function () {
            var o = options;
            var carousel = this;
            $carousel_container = $(carousel).find(".carousel_container");
            $li = $(carousel).find(".carousel_container ul li");
            var visible_width = parseInt($carousel_container.css("width"), 10);
            var visible_height = parseInt($carousel_container.css("height"), 10);
            var number_items = $li.size();
            var item_width = parseInt($li.css("width"), 10);
            var item_height = parseInt($li.css("height"), 10);
            var item_marginRight = parseInt($li.css("marginRight"), 10);
            var item_marginLeft = parseInt($li.css("marginLeft"), 10);
            var item_marginTop = parseInt($li.css("marginTop"), 10);
            var item_marginBottom = parseInt($li.css("marginBottom"), 10);
            if (o.orientation == "horizontal") {
                var visible_items = Math.ceil(visible_width / (item_width + item_marginRight + item_marginLeft));
            } else {
                var visible_items = Math.ceil(visible_height / (item_height + item_marginTop + item_marginBottom));
            }
            var slides = Math.ceil(number_items / visible_items);
            $float_easing = "easeInOutQuart";

            function set_item_classes_visibility() {
                $li.each(function (index) {
                    var class_number = Math.floor((index + visible_items) / visible_items);
                    $(this).addClass("visible_" + class_number);
                    if (class_number == "1") {
                        $(this).css("display", "block");
                        $(this).find(".inner").css("display", "block");
                    } else {
                        $(this).css("display", "none");
                        $(this).find(".inner").css("display", "none");
                    }
                });
            }
            set_item_classes_visibility();

            function set_next_prev_classes() {
                var visible_item_class = $(carousel).find(".carousel_container ul li:visible").attr("class");
                var visible_id = visible_item_class.split("_");
                if (!o.loop) {
                    if (visible_id[1] == "1") {
                        $(".carousel_prev").addClass("disable");
                    } else {
                        $(".carousel_prev").removeClass("disable");
                    }
                    if (visible_id[1] == slides) {
                        $(".carousel_next").addClass("disable");
                    } else {
                        $(".carousel_next").removeClass("disable");
                    }
                }
            }
            set_next_prev_classes();

            function set_item_position() {
                $li.each(function () {
                    $(this).css("display", "none");
                    $(this).css("position", "absolute");
                    if (o.orientation == "horizontal") {
                        $(this).css("top", "0");
                        $(this).css("left", visible_width + parseInt($carousel_container.css("paddingLeft")) + parseInt($carousel_container.css("paddingRight")), 10);
                    } else {
                        if (o.orientation == "vertical") {
                            $(this).css("left", "0");
                            $(this).css("top", visible_height + parseInt($carousel_container.css("paddingTop")) + parseInt($carousel_container.css("paddingBottom")), 10);
                        }
                    }
                });
                $carousel_container.find("li.visible_1").each(function (index) {
                    $(this).css("display", "block");
                    if (o.orientation == "horizontal") {
                        var left_position = (index * (item_width + item_marginRight + item_marginLeft)) + parseInt($carousel_container.css("paddingLeft"), 10);
                        $(this).css("left", left_position);
                    } else {
                        if (o.orientation == "vertical") {
                            var top_position = (index * (item_height + item_marginTop + item_marginBottom)) + parseInt($carousel_container.css("paddingTop"), 10);
                            $(this).css("top", top_position);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            if (o.effect == "slide") {
                set_item_position();
            }
            function show_next_prev(method) {
                function show_items_fade(id) {
                    var next_class_name = "visible_" + id;
                    $carousel_container.find("li." + next_class_name).css("display", "block");
                    $carousel_container.find("li." + next_class_name).each(function (index) {
                        var delay = (index) * o.delay;
                        if (method == "prev") {
                            var delay = ((visible_items - 1) - index) * o.delay;
                        }
                        var index_item = (index + 1);
                        $(this).find(".inner").delay(delay).fadeIn(o.fade, function () {
                            if (index_item == visible_items || id == slides) {
                                set_next_prev_classes();
                            }
                        });
                    });
                }
                function show_items_slide(id) {
                    var next_class_name = "visible_" + id;
                    $carousel_container.find("li." + next_class_name + " .inner").css("display", "block");
                    $carousel_container.find("li." + next_class_name).each(function (index) {
                        $(this).css("display", "block");
                        var delay = (index) * o.delay;
                        if (method == "prev") {
                            var delay = ((visible_items - 1) - index) * o.delay;
                        }
                        var index_item = (index + 1);
                        if (o.orientation == "horizontal") {
                            var left_position = (index * (item_width + item_marginRight + item_marginLeft)) + parseInt($carousel_container.css("paddingLeft"), 10);
                            $(this).delay(delay).animate({
                                left: left_position
                            }, o.slide, $float_easing, function () {
                                if (index_item == visible_items || id == slides) {
                                    set_next_prev_classes();
                                }
                            });
                        } else {
                            if (o.orientation == "vertical") {
                                var top_position = (index * (item_height + item_marginTop + item_marginBottom)) + parseInt($carousel_container.css("paddingTop"), 10);
                                $(this).delay(delay).animate({
                                    top: top_position
                                }, o.slide, $float_easing, function () {
                                    if (index_item == visible_items || id == slides) {
                                        set_next_prev_classes();
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
                var visible_item_class = $carousel_container.find("li:visible").attr("class");
                visible_id = visible_item_class.split("_");
                var next_id = parseInt(visible_id[1], 10) + 1;
                var prev_id = parseInt(visible_id[1], 10) - 1;
                if (visible_id[1] == 1) {
                    prev_id = slides;
                }
                if (visible_id[1] == slides) {
                    next_id = 1;
                }
                switch (o.effect) {
                    case "fade":
                        $carousel_container.find("li:visible").each(function (index) {
                            var delay = (index) * o.delay;
                            var index_item = (index + 1);
                            var last_item = $carousel_container.find("li." + visible_item_class).size();
                            if (method == "prev") {
                                delay = ((visible_items - 1) - index) * o.delay;
                                last_item = 1;
                            }
                            $(this).find(".inner").delay(delay).fadeOut(o.fade, function () {
                                if (index_item == last_item) {
                                    $("li." + visible_item_class).css("display", "none");
                                    if (method == "next") {
                                        show_items_fade(next_id);
                                    } else {
                                        if (method == "prev") {
                                            show_items_fade(prev_id);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        });
                        break;
                    case "slide":
                        $carousel_container.find("li.visible_" + prev_id).each(function (index) {
                            if (o.orientation == "horizontal") {
                                if (method == "next") {
                                    var left_position = visible_width + parseInt($carousel_container.css("paddingLeft"), 10) + parseInt($carousel_container.css("paddingRight"), 10);
                                } else {
                                    if (method == "prev") {
                                        var left_position = "-" + item_width + "px";
                                    }
                                }
                                $(this).css("left", left_position);
                            } else {
                                if (o.orientation == "vertical") {
                                    if (method == "next") {
                                        var top_position = visible_height + parseInt($carousel_container.css("paddingTop"), 10) + parseInt($carousel_container.css("paddingBottom"), 10);
                                    } else {
                                        if (method == "prev") {
                                            var top_position = "-" + item_height + "px";
                                        }
                                    }
                                    $(this).css("top", top_position);
                                }
                            }
                        });
                        $carousel_container.find("li." + visible_item_class).each(function (index) {
                            var delay = (index) * o.delay;
                            var zindex = index + 10;
                            var index_item = (index + 1);
                            var last_item = $carousel_container.find("li." + visible_item_class).size();
                            if (method == "prev") {
                                delay = ((visible_items - 1) - index) * o.delay;
                                zindex = ((visible_items - 1) - index) + 10;
                                last_item = 1;
                            }
                            $(this).css("z-index", zindex);
                            if (o.orientation == "horizontal") {
                                if (method == "next") {
                                    var left_position = "-" + item_width;
                                } else {
                                    if (method == "prev") {
                                        var left_position = visible_width + parseInt($carousel_container.css("paddingLeft"), 10) + parseInt($carousel_container.css("paddingRight"), 10);
                                    }
                                }
                                $(this).delay(delay).animate({
                                    left: left_position
                                }, o.slide, $float_easing, function () {
                                    if (index_item == last_item) {
                                        $("li." + visible_item_class).css("display", "none");
                                        if (method == "next") {
                                            show_items_slide(next_id);
                                        } else {
                                            if (method == "prev") {
                                                show_items_slide(prev_id);
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                            } else {
                                if (o.orientation == "vertical") {
                                    if (method == "next") {
                                        var top_position = "-" + item_height;
                                    } else {
                                        if (method == "prev") {
                                            var top_position = visible_height + parseInt($carousel_container.css("paddingTop"), 10) + parseInt($carousel_container.css("paddingBottom"), 10);
                                        }
                                    }
                                    $(this).delay(delay).animate({
                                        top: top_position
                                    }, o.slide, $float_easing, function () {
                                        if (index_item == last_item) {
                                            $("li." + visible_item_class).css("display", "none");
                                            if (method == "next") {
                                                show_items_slide(next_id);
                                            } else {
                                                if (method == "prev") {
                                                    show_items_slide(prev_id);
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                            }
                        });
                        break;
                }
            }
            if (o.autoplay) {
                var interval = setInterval(function () {
                    var visible_item_class = $(carousel).find(".carousel_container ul li:visible").attr("class");
                    var visible_id = visible_item_class.split("_");
                    if (!o.loop) {
                        if (visible_id[1] == slides) {
                            clearInterval(interval);
                        } else {
                            show_next_prev("next");
                        }
                    } else {
                        show_next_prev("next");
                    }
                }, o.time);
            }
            $(carousel).find(".carousel_next").click(function () {
                clearInterval(interval);
                show_next_prev("next");
                return (false);
            });
            $(carousel).find(".carousel_prev").click(function () {
                clearInterval(interval);
                show_next_prev("prev");
                return (false);
            });
            $li.hover(function () {
                clearInterval(interval);
                $(this).find(".caption").fadeIn(o.captionFade);
            }, function () {
                $(this).find(".caption").fadeOut(o.captionFade);
            });
        });
    }
});
})(jQuery);
```

I'm thinking if there is some way I can identify each carousel with an ID and the script only executes things within each ID it would work, but I can't figure out how to get it done.

EDIT: I am getting the following js console error when I click a next/prev button: `visible_item_class is undefined`

Comment: what do you mean breaks does none of them work?

Comment: i'm not familiar with how jcarousel works, but if you just want to make a carousel from id, just use $('#your-id').mycarousel(), instead of giving a class.

Comment: @ShubhamSharma: What I mean is that if there is more than 1 on a page, each time you click a next/prev button, it tries to control all of the carousels and messes up the display of the images.

Answer (score 0):

Give them each an unique ID and call them by that.

```
$('#carousel1').mycarousel({
    theid: $(this).attr('id'),
    delay: 150,
    fade:300,
    slide: 700,
    effect:'slide',                   
    orientation:'horizontal',
    loop: false,
    autoplay: false
});

$('#carousel2').mycarousel({
    theid: $(this).attr('id'),
    delay: 150,
    fade:300,
    slide: 700,
    effect:'slide',                   
    orientation:'horizontal',
    loop: false,
    autoplay: false
});
```

On a side note is the following line necessary:
`theid: $(this).attr('id')`

I don't see it used anywhere in the carousel code.

Comment: I just tried that and it doesnt work. I think it has something to do with the next/prev buttons. When I click them it scrambles up both carousels.

Comment: Is finding another carousel plugin an option for you?  Many will advertise being able to have more than one on a page as a feature so it shouldn't be all that hard to find a replacement.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the function `set_next_prev_classes` in the plugin, the problem is probably that your 'next' and 'previous' buttons share a common class. (The plugin shouldn't do things this way, but there it is anyway.)

The solution should be as simple as giving each carousel DISTINCT class names for their 'next' and 'previous' buttons -- this can be as simple as appending the numbers 1 and 2 to each. (And then tell the plugin author that this approach is causing problems.)

Comment: I am getting the following js console error: `visible_item_class is undefined`

Comment: The plugin has the following line: `var visible_item_class = $(carousel).find(".carousel_container ul li:visible").attr("class");` -- you might have changed the structure of your HTML such that it can't find the next/prev button.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to fix the problem.

1. Change the carousel code to take id of the div used as carousel , and carousel controls.
2. Copy the carousel code two times.Replace ".carousel" with "#Id1" in first and "#Id2" in second.
   Then the controls will be "#Id1_next", "#Id1_prev".
   This is kind of hacky but cant help it.